# Make Widget visible when another widget is triggered

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I don't really know that much about flutter, but what has to be done...
I am creating a "Preferences"-Menu right now, with one Menu entry that should be greyed out as long as the one above is not enabled. I have struggled to find any solution to this, which seemed pretty strange as it is basic behaviour.

After some time I found the approach of using Listenables, which I have tried. But for some reason it does not work, can someone tell me why? The lower entry just keeps the initial value.

*main.dart*

```dart
class SettingList extends StatelessWidget  {

  final handler = new ValueNotifier(false);

  Widget titleSync = Text(
    'Entry 1'
  );

  Widget titleSet = Text(
      'Entry 2'
  );

  Widget subTitleSet = Text(
      'Entry 2 Subheading'
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(children: <Widget>[
      SwitchOption(titleSync, handler),
      ListOption(titleSet, subTitleSet, handler)
    ],
    );
  }
}
```

*sync.dart*

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class _SwitchOptionState extends State<SwitchOption> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ValueListenableBuilder<bool>(
        valueListenable: widget.handler,
        builder: (context, value, child) {
          return SwitchListTile(
              value: widget._toggle,
              title: widget.title,
              onChanged: (bool value) {
                setState(() {
                  if(value == true){
                    widget.handler.value = true;
                  }else{
                    widget.handler.value = false;
                  }
                  widget._toggle = value;
                });
              }
          );
        },
    );
  }
}

class SwitchOption extends StatefulWidget {
  SwitchOption(this.title, this.handler);
  ValueNotifier<bool> handler;
  bool _toggle = false;

  final Widget title;

  @override
  _SwitchOptionState createState() => _SwitchOptionState();
}
```

*syncSettings.dart*

```dart
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class _ListOptionState extends State<ListOption> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      title: widget.title,
      subtitle: widget.subtitle,
      onTap: (widget.handler.value == true ) ? (){print("Test");} : null
    );
  }
}

class ListOption extends StatefulWidget {
  ListOption(this.title, this.subtitle, this.handler);
  bool _toggle = false;
  final ValueListenable<bool> handler;

  final Widget title;
  final Widget subtitle;

  @override
  _ListOptionState createState() => _ListOptionState();
}
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure how to use the ValueNotifier, but it seems to that you could easily omit the ValueNotifier, and just move the state up. Convert your SettingsList to a StatefulWidget, keep the boolean in it's state, and pass it down to the other widgets. Will provide a solution in an answer in abit!

Answer (score 0):

So, I changed your code so that the toggle state is moved up, and ValueListener is not used anymore. I also refactored some code:

- only passing String to your widgets now, the text widgets get built in the lower level widgets.
- ListOption is now a stateless widget

main.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:test_project/sync.dart';
import 'package:test_project/syncSettings.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: SettingList(),
    );
  }
}

class SettingList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SettingListState createState() => _SettingListState();
}

class _SettingListState extends State<SettingList> {
  bool _toggle = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          SwitchOption(
            'Entry 1',
            onToggle,
          ),
          ListOption(
            'Entry 2',
            'Entry 2 Subheading',
            _toggle,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void onToggle(bool value) {
    print("Changed");
    setState(() {
      _toggle = value;
    });
  }
}
```

sync.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SwitchOption extends StatefulWidget {
  SwitchOption(this._title, this._onChanged);

  final String _title;
  final Function _onChanged;

  @override
  _SwitchOptionState createState() => _SwitchOptionState();
}

class _SwitchOptionState extends State<SwitchOption> {
  bool _localValue = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SwitchListTile(
        value: _localValue,
        title: Text(widget._title),
        onChanged: (value) {
          setState(() {
            _localValue = value;
          });
          widget._onChanged(value);
        });
  }
}
```

syncSettings.dart: converted to stateless widget and passing the state from the top widget

```
class ListOption extends StatelessWidget {
  ListOption(this._title, this._subtitle, this._isEnabled);

  final String _title;
  final String _subtitle;
  final bool _isEnabled;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(_title),
      subtitle: Text(_subtitle),
      enabled: _isEnabled,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I expected much in response to my question, which basically screams "I have no idea of flutter". But I definitly did not expect someone answer that nicely and even refactor my code. Thank you so much. Cheers.

Comment: To add some more options: what I did here would be considered 'lifting state up', but what you were trying to do, can be accomplished in a few other ways as well. Check the docs about state management; particularly the part about ChangeNotifier: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple